# 5000: The class '...' must subclass 'flash.display.BitmapData' since it is linked to a library symbol of that type

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm new here and need your help.
I'm trying to compile a Flash Movie and I'll get this error...
I don't know how to fix ist.
Could you help me with this? 
I get this error:

> 5000: The class misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty must subclass
>   'flash.display.BitmapData' since it is linked to a library symbol of
>   that type.

this is the as-script

> package  {
>
> ```
> import mx.core.*;     
> import flash.display.BitmapData;
>
> public class misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty extends BitmapAsset
> {
>
>     public function misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty()
>     {
>         return;
>     }
>
> } }
> ```

sorry for my bad english^^

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured it out now but

Change

```
public class misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty extends BitmapAsset
```

To

```
public class misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty extends BitmapData
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it out.
I can compile it now, but if I try to play the compiled swf, it close itself.
Is it possible to compile my .fla, Without the compiler checked the as-files for correctness?

The original-swf works with `public class misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty extends BitmapAsset` 
I decompiled it, but everytime I recompile it, I get this error.

Comment: @ChrisX930 Maybe you shouldn't decompile the original SWF first? If you are doing that legitly, try contacting the developer for his sources. Apparently he has used not Flash CSx to make that SWF, most likely it was a Flex compiler, so maybe try compiling that FLA in Flex.

Comment: Fixed it by myself. 
Only added [Embed(source="misc_Embeds__e_BarEmpty.png")]`